# Why doesn't {% if %} {% else %} construction work in Django template?

Tags: django

So I am trying to display "YOU" above the comment if it's in fact a comment that has been posted by current user, otherwise I am trying to display just a username of one who left a comment.

But somehow if/else doesn't work. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thank you beforehand!

my models.py

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    commented_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=300)

def __str__(self):
    return self.comment
```

my forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = ['comment']

        widgets = {'comment': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 5})}
```

my views.py

```
class Comment(CreateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'app/comments.html'
    login_url = 'login'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('comments')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.commented_by = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        if self.object:
            messages.success(self.request, 'Success')
        else:
            messages.error(self.request, 'Error')
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['comment'] = 'Please leave your comment here'
        return initial

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context['comments'] = Comments.objects.all()
        return context
```

and my condition from the template:

```
<div>
    <div class="commentsContainer">
            {% for comment in comments %}
        {% if comment.commented_by == user.username %}
        <h4>YOU</h4>
        {% else %}
        {{comment.commented_by}}
        {% endif %}
        <div class="comment">
            {{comment}}
        </div>
            {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: try this ```{% if comment.commented_by.username == user.username %}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`comment.commented_by` will give you an instance of the user model, whereas `user.username` will give you a *string* which is the user's username. Hence `comment.commented_by == user.username` will always give you `False`. Instead you should write:

```
{% if comment.commented_by == user %}
    <h4>YOU</h4>
{% else %}
    {{ comment.commented_by }}
{% endif %}
```